# Different ways for implementing Memory Management

Tags: memory-management, z80

The story is the following, I'm building a Z80 based computer from scratch, by that I mean, taking a Z80, Peripherals, RAM and ROM and soldering them to together. But once that is done I'll end up with more than 64K of RAM (I'm using memory banks for getting more memory than the Z80 is capable of addressing), which I don't know how to manage. My idea is to program a simple lisp interpreter on the computer but I would also like dynamic arrays or string for which I clearly need something like malloc.

So the question is, once you have a block of continuous memory, how do you fragment it and manage it?

and

Could you tell me some methods/algorithms in which this is done?, I would like to keep it simple but also not being lazy and doing it right.

Answer (score 4):

You need at least some what is called 'common' space in classic Z80 terminology. You can't switch all the memory at once or you lose your instructions and stack.

If for example you have 32K fixed, 32K banked (which is by far the easiest to wire) then you would allocate a bunch of banks to your data. You then need a standard allocator (first/last fit) for each bank, and to simply iterate over banks to find one with room. In other words the problem isn't a 'banked malloc' problem it's a for loop of ordinary malloc problems and there are a ton of trival malloc implementations for small machines.

For free/realloc you also need to remember the bank number. Realloc is slightly trickier as the data may move bank.

The hard case with data is if you want to try and keep some things together (eg so you can compare two strings without copying or continual bank switching)

I think I'd have started with a 68000 if I was building a lisp machine however 8)

Something like the tiny68K 
https://retrobrewcomputers.org/doku.php?id=boards:sbc:tiny68k

Answer (score 3):

(This is in addition to [Alan Cox answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50529961/2973400))

If there are differnt data types (And Lisp does have them :)), it may be usefull to use this type as primary criteria and always assign a whole bank to a type (or maybe a group of similar ones) and then allocate items within banks assinged to its type. Rational is that data of one type usually interact more often with its kind than play with the other kids. Aranging them close to each other will help to reduce bank switching. This is especially true for strings.

While this may seam as waste of space, it does reduce search (depending on banking structure ofc). Depending on the amount of blocks available (and data shoveled) it'll equal out soon.

Similar, when allocating it *may* be useful to allocate all new data into the last assigned block of this type instead of searching for holes in any previous. Again for speed concerns, when storing the new data, but as well to reduce garbage collection time.

Only when the latest added block is filled up the block may be reorganized - or if that doesn't seam much worthy the whole group for that data type. This brings two advantages: for one, only the banks used for this data type (group) have to be reorganized, not the data memory as whole, saving on garbage collection time. Second, and maybe more important, over time least used date will move to 'early' blocks of that type, while often changed ones move to the end. This again will reduce banking need, as now data that has been proven to change a lot (and thus beeing accessed a lot) resides close to each other and maybe even within a single block.

Bottom line is to try to change the disadvantage of a block orientated (banked) memory into an advantage.